# How can multiple identical values be printed from an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to create a basic concordance script that will print the ten words before and after the value found inside an array. I did this by splitting the text into an array, identifying the position of the value, and then printing -10 and +10 with the searched value in the middle. However, this only presents the first such occurrence. I know I can find the others by using *array_keys* (found in positions 52, 78, 80), but I'm not quite sure how to cycle through the matches, since *array_keys* also results in an array. Thus, using $matches (with *array_keys*) in place of $location below doesn't work, since you cannot use the same operands on an array as an integer. Any suggestions? Thank you!!

```
<?php

$text = <<<EOD
The spread of a deadly new virus is accelerating, Chinese President Xi Jinping warned, after holding a special government meeting on the Lunar New Year public holiday.
The country is facing a "grave situation" Mr Xi told senior officials.
The coronavirus has killed at least 42 people and infected some 1,400 since its discovery in the city of Wuhan.
Meanwhile, UK-based researchers have warned of a real possibility that China will not be able to contain the virus.
Travel restrictions have come in place in several affected cities. From Sunday, private vehicles will be banned from central districts of Wuhan, the source of the outbreak.
EOD;

$new = explode(" ", $text);
$location = array_search("in", $new, FALSE);
$concordance = 10;

$top_range = $location + $concordance;
$bottom_range = $location - $concordance;

while($bottom_range <= $top_range) {
    echo $new[$bottom_range] . " ";
    $bottom_range++;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just iterate over the values returned by [`array_keys`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php), using [`array_slice`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to extract the `$concordance` words either side of the location and [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode) to put the sentence back together again:

```
$words = explode(' ', $text);
$concordance = 10;
$results = array();
foreach (array_keys($words, 'in') as $idx) {
    $results[] = implode(' ', array_slice($words, max($idx - $concordance, 0), $concordance * 2 + 1));
}
print_r($results);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => least 42 people and infected some 1,400 since its discovery in the city of Wuhan.
Meanwhile, UK-based researchers have warned of a
    [1] => not be able to contain the virus.
Travel restrictions have come in place in several affected cities. From Sunday, private vehicles will
    [2] => able to contain the virus.
Travel restrictions have come in place in several affected cities. From Sunday, private vehicles will be banned
)
```

If you want to avoid generating similar phrases where a word occurs twice within `$concordance` words (e.g. indexes 1 and 2 in the above array), you can maintain a position for the end of the last match, and skip occurrences that occur in that match:

```
$words = explode(' ', $text);
$concordance = 10;
$results = array();
$last = 0;
foreach (array_keys($words, 'in') as $idx) {
    if ($idx < $last) continue;
    $results[] = implode(' ', array_slice($words, max($idx - $concordance, 0), $concordance * 2 + 1));
    $last = $idx + $concordance;
}
print_r($results);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => least 42 people and infected some 1,400 since its discovery in the city of Wuhan.
Meanwhile, UK-based researchers have warned of a
    [1] => not be able to contain the virus.
Travel restrictions have come in place in several affected cities. From Sunday, private vehicles will
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/9aa8Z)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
<?php

$text = <<<EOD
The spread of a deadly new virus is accelerating, Chinese President Xi Jinping warned, after holding a special government meeting on the Lunar New Year public holiday.
The country is facing a "grave situation" Mr Xi told senior officials.
The coronavirus has killed at least 42 people and infected some 1,400 since its discovery in the city of Wuhan.
Meanwhile, UK-based researchers have warned of a real possibility that China will not be able to contain the virus.
Travel restrictions have come in place in several affected cities. From Sunday, private vehicles will be banned from central districts of Wuhan, the source of the outbreak.
EOD;

$words = explode(" ", $text);
$concordance = 10; // range -+
$result = []; // result array
$index = 0;

if (count($words) === 0) // be sure there is no empty array
    exit;

do {
    $location = array_search("in", $words, false);

    if (!$location) // break loop if $location not found
        break;

    $count = count($words);

    // check range of array indexes
    $minRange = ($location - $concordance > 0) ? ($location-$concordance) : 0; // array can't have index less than 0 (shorthand if)
    $maxRange = (($location + $concordance) < ($count - 1)) ? ($location+$concordance) : $count - 1; // array can't have index equal or higher than array count (shorthand if)

    for ($range = $minRange; $range < $maxRange; $range++) {
        $result[$index][] = $words[$range]; // group words by index
    }

    unset($words[$location]); // delete element which contain "in"
    $words = array_values($words); // reindex array
    $index++;
} while ($location); // repeat until $location exist


print_r($result); // <--- here's your results

?>
```